# Newbie writing methods - counting words in a string

Tags: methods, counting

Yes, this is homework but I'm seeking help. I've read over the book we have and I've tried to work with a team of people and I've tried searching here and online elsewhere.

I sort of have this working. It asks for a string twice (should only ask once) and it seems to give the error message if the user enters a blank code. However, it repeats "your string has 1 words in it. your string has 2 words in it. your string has 3 words in it. your string has 4 words in it. your string has 5 words in it." and then repeats again - no matter how many words the string has in it. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and appreciate any help.

```
/*
 * Lab07a.java
 * 
 *   A simple program that computes the number of words in an input string.
 *   Used to practice breaking code up into methods. 
 * 
 * @author ENTER YOUR NAMES HERE
 * 
 */
package osu.cse1223;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Lab07a {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //get scanner//
    getInputString(keyboard);
    String input = getInputString(keyboard);
    int count = getWordCount(input);
   }

// Given a Scanner, prompt the user for a String.  If the user enters an empty
// String, report an error message and ask for a non-empty String.  Return the
// String to the calling program.

private static String getInputString(Scanner keyboardScanner) {
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String str = keyboardScanner.nextLine();
    if (str.length() ==0)
    {
        System.out.print("ERROR - string must not be empty");
    }

    return str;
}

// Given a String return the number of words in the String.  A word is a sequence of 
    // characters with no spaces.  Write this method so that the function call:
    // int count = getWordCount("The quick brown fox jumped");
    // results in count having a value of 5.  You will call this method from the main method.
    // For this assignment you may assume that
    // words will be separated by exactly one space.
    private static int getWordCount(String str) {
    int spaces = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <str.length())
        {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch == ' ')
        i++;
        {

        spaces++;
    System.out.print("Your string has " + spaces + "words in it." );
    }
        }
    return spaces;
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you have an equivalent of str.partition (python) so that it'd return an array of your splitted string including the separator (space here) and then you'd just have to compare the length of str.split with str.partition and the difference is the number of spaces.

Comment: Try all = text.split(" ", -1) which seems to be str.partition equivalent and compare with words = text.split(). So at the end, spaces = len(all) - len(words), this is the idea.

Comment: Might depend on the problem specification, but if I'd assigned this, I'd be looking for the student to solve the problem, and would specifically disallow using an existing function that solves the problem for them.  Sort of "don't use Java's split function -- I want you to do it yourself."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's asking you for the string twice is that you tell it to, right here:

```
getInputString(keyboard); //HERE YOU ASK FOR AN INPUT STRING
String input = getInputString(keyboard); //HERE YOU ASK FOR IT AGAIN
```

Ask for it *once* instead, store the result, and go on.

The best answer to your main problem is to consider the algorithm, the plan you have for counting those spaces.  Write it out in English and be sure you believe it before putting it into Java.  Here's what you're doing right now:

```
while we haven't reached end of string
   if the current character is a space
      go further in the string
   else
      add 1 to the number of spaces found so far
      print the number of spaces found so far
```

Now, this is clearly not what you mean.  For one thing, why go further in the string ONLY if you reach a space?  For another, why would you add 1 to the number of spaces found so far if you DON'T find a space?  And why print the number of spaces found so far -- every time you go through the loop -- but only if you don't find a space?

No wonder it's printing 1 space found, 2 spaces, 3 spaces, etc.

Planning ahead by writing the algorithm in English is essential to avoiding problems like this.

So:  take this algorithm and change it so it says what you want it to say, still in English -- then convert to Java.

One further hint:  your indenting looks random toward the end.  That makes it harder to see if you made a mistake.  Pay rigorous attention to the indentation, and you'll be better able to detect if there are problems.

Answer (score -1):

Move this line

System.out.print("Your string has " + spaces + "words in it." );

Out of loop that should solve your prob. No 1

I really doubt if its doing the printing two times though.

However I must say there are better ways to do it.
str.split(" ");
is one of them

**EDIT**
Are you invoking getWordsCount two times, sadly something wrong with formatting on my phone's soclient right now